# Как заменить в строке все пробелы на тэг переноса строки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, есть строка "Текст текст текст". Как при клике на определенную кнопки все пробелы заменить на тэг переноса строки, чтобы строка стала такой:

> ```
> Текст
> текст
> текст
> ```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрите `replace()` как вариант.

```js
$(".submit").click(function() {
  var space = / /gi;
  var str = "aaa bbb ccc";
  var newStr = str.replace(space, '<br>');
  console.log(newStr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="submit">
```